# Very slow mail sending with Django send_mail method

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I use django (1.5.2) to send mail each day. About 100 or so in a ~ 2/3 minutes interval.

I never really had any problem until lately (It's possible since I upgraded to 1.5.2). Now it takes sometimes up to 2 hours (!) to send these mails.

What happens is that I have a maximum of 5 threads trying to send mails using the send_mail method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail). When a thread is done, a new one is created, do some work and then send a mail. When it's time to send, they all "stop" (or dead lock or something) for sometimes minutes, sometimes hours, until finally they send their mails and everything works fine again (the next threads send their mails quickly).

I use postfix and a gmail account as the mail server. When sending only one mail (in the django shell or when a thread send one mail at another hour) there are no problem (the mail is sent instantly). Each send_mail call is done with about 4 recipients, so that's 100 ~ 4 * 25 about.

Finally when looking at mail.info log, every log is timestamped around the time the mail is actually sent, maybe suggestion the problem lies in django ?

The thing is I have no idea how to debug this, where should I look, and if the problem comes from django or gmail. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: If you're sending from Django to a Postfix on localhost, send_mail should be almost instantaneous. There is some info on setting up Postfix here: http://stackful-dev.com/django-email-tricks-part-2.html, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps set up [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html) instead of threads?

Also you could use an emailing service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) and not have to worry about the load of mailing. Just hit their API by REST or using SMTP

Comment: I didn't try sendgrid but did switch to celery for mail sending. Actually the slowness was as much a problem of database as it was of sending the actual mail.